# ios/objective-c: Detect tabbarbutton pressed event

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to prevent users from going to certain view controllers accessible through tab bar bar buttons and instead ask them to log in with an alert.  I can disable the buttons, however, the only way to detect a button press on a disabled tab bar button (in order to fire the alert) seems to be to embed the button in another view with a gesture recognizer which seems complicated.

Alternatively, if I leave the buttons enabled, upon press they launch the view controller to which they are assigned with no way to launch the alert.

Is there a way to detect the press and pre-empt the segue to the view controller so I can launch an alert?

I have tried using the following method in my app delegate and in viewdidload of individual view controllers (that subscribe to uitabbarcontroller delegate protocol) but it is not getting fired.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    NSUInteger indexOfTab = [theTabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    NSLog(@"Tab index pressed = %lu", (unsigned long)indexOfTab);
    //launch alert
//prevent segue to view controller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you have to implement in your `UITabBarController` is :

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

If user is logged you return YES, if he's not, show an alert and return NO. You can check for which item was pressed by comparing viewController with the one(s) you want user to be logged.

You don't have to implement this method in a controller that subscribes to `UITabBarController` delegate protocol BUT to implement it in a subclass of your `UITabBarController`.